# Insert Invoice into Exact Online

Tags: sql, exact-online, invantive-sql, invantive-control

I want to insert an Invoice into Exact Online. When I insert the invoice manual, it works fine, but with the Invantive Control tool I get an error:

```
insert into UploadXMLTopics
( topic
, payload
, division_code
, orig_system_reference
, orig_system_group
) 
select 'Invoices'
,      '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
|| '<eExact xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="eExact-XML.xsd">'
|| '    <Invoices>'
|| '        <Invoice>'
|| '          <Journal code="70"/>'
|| '            <Description>Test invoice</Description>'
|| '            <YourRef>Your name</YourRef>'
|| '            <Notes>Test note</Notes>'
|| '            <OrderedBy ID="{c3b73aa4-c5c1-49bc-8a76-2802a26c5973}" code="289" />'   
|| '            <DeliverTo ID="{c3b73aa4-c5c1-49bc-8a76-2802a26c5973}" code="289" />'       
|| '            <InvoiceTo ID="{c3b73aa4-c5c1-49bc-8a76-2802a26c5973}" code="289" />'   
|| '            <PaymentCondition code="30" />'
|| '            <SalesPerson id="{92e96458-82ba-4a1f-a056-61bda3b42f04}" />'
|| '            <InvoiceLine line="1">'
|| '                <Description>Article name</Description>'
|| '                <Item code="0003" />'
|| '                <Quantity>2</Quantity>'
|| '                <Note><![CDATA[THIS IS A NOTEDIT IS EEN NOTITIE]]></Note>'
|| '            </InvoiceLine>'
|| '        </Invoice>'
|| '    </Invoices>'
|| '</eExact>'
,     123456,
,     'Create-invoice-1'
,     'Create-invoice'
from  me
```

The error I get:

```
[12292] Total execution time: 562 ms at level 0: 'Run SQL action insert into UploadXMLTopics ( topic , payload , division_code , orig_system_reference , orig_system_group )  select 'Invoices', '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' || '<eExact xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="eExact-XML.xsd">' || ' <Invoices>' || '  <Invoice>' || '    <Journal code="70"/>' || '   <Description>Test invoice</Description>' || '   <YourRef>Your name</YourRef>' || '   <Notes>Test note</Notes>' || '   <OrderedBy ID="{c3b73aa4-c5c1-49bc-8a76-2802a26c5973}" code="289" />'  || '   <DeliverTo ID="{c3b73aa4-c5c1-49bc-8a76-2802a26c5973}" code="289" />'   || '   <InvoiceTo ID="{c3b73aa4-c5c1-49bc-8a76-2802a26c5973}" code="289" />'  || '   <PaymentCondition code="30" />' || '   <SalesPerson id="{92e96458-82ba-4a1f-a056-61bda3b42f04}" />' || '   <InvoiceLine line="1">' || '    <Description>Article name</Description>' || '    <Item code="0003" />' || '    <Quantity>2</Quantity>' || '    <Note><![CDATA[THIS IS A NOTE]]></Note>' || '   </InvoiceLine>' || '  </Invoice>' || ' </Invoices>' || '</eExact>', 123456, 'Create-invoice-1', 'Create-invoice' from me '. 
[12292] Saving 175 SQL History items to 'C:\Users\fleemkuil\Invantive\Prd\Invantive Query Tool\sqlhistory.xml'.
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you list actually isn't an error. It is just some logging the framework does.

You have to check the `UploadXMLTopics` table to see if the execution was successful or not.

For example:

```
select successful
,      result
,      result_errors
from   UploadXMLTopics
where  orig_system_reference = 'Create-invoice-1'
```

Make sure to check the `result` and `result_errors` columns to see what caused an upload to fail.