# Is it possible to create a sales order in Exact Online using REST API of Invantive Control

Tags: exact-online, invantive-sql, invantive-control

I want to create a Sales Order in Exact Online in the table SalesOrders.

This works using the REST API controlled by Invantive Control.

However, Exact Online reports that the sales order lines are missing.

How can I create the salesorder, since in Exact Online a salesorder as well as salesorderlines have to be created.

Or is this best done by XML API?

Answer (score 1):

For high volume loads across multiple divisions: use scenario described on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42955321/insert-invoice-into-exact-online%20%22StackOverflow%20question%22.)

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on this please? I am also interested in ways to creates sales order from outside of Exact Online and automatically have them entered into the latter.